# #1264 - Out of range value for column 'quantity' at row 3610

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I’m trying to import values from table t1 to t2 and I’m getting the following error

> #1264 - Out of range value for column 'quantity' at row 3610

In t1 I have  --> quantity DECIMAL(12,4) DEFAULT ‘0.0000’,
but in t2  the quantity is --> quantity decimal(10,4),

is there a way convert t1 quantity to decimal(10,4) ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Will it matter that your values will lose precision when doing this conversion?  Going from 12 to 10 is quite the loss

Comment: I dont think so the max lenght I have is (7,4) this is an example qty -->1000000.0000

Comment: *is there a way convert t1 quantity to decimal(10,4) ?* Noway without data loss. Alter table t2 and set its column to `DECIMAL(12,4)`.

Comment: @anasshl You must be losing precision otherwise you wouldn't be receiving the error!

Comment: *I dont think so the max lenght I have is (7,4) this is an example qty -->1000000.0000*. No. 7 is **total** digits amount, 4 is amount of digits after decimal point, so only 3 digits before the decimal point is allowed.

Comment: As it seems The problem is that I was trying to fit a large number (12 digits) into a field that can only contain 10 digits.
What I did is converting the receiving table so that it has a larger field.